# How to disable the keyboard and mouse via assembly code

Tags: assembly, keyboard, mouse, dos, interrupt

I have tried to write an assembly code to hang the keyboard and mouse (I try with keyboard now) . I searched in everywhere nearly (in references and articles and the old topic here also) and almost all show the same code by fetch the address of INT 9 and create new interrupt then make it be called rather than the original interrupt(9) . That is my code i had written:

```
.model tiny    
.stack 100h
.data
    old_ISR dd ?
.code
main proc far
    mov ah,35h                ; get interrupt vector
    mov al,09                 ; for int 9  
    INT 21h  
    mov word ptr old_ISR,BX   ; address of original int9 saved  
    mov word ptr old_ISR,ES   ; in ES:BX
    mov ah,25h                ; set interrupt vector
    mov al,09h                ; for int 9
    mov DX,offset ISR         ;is pointing to my ISR
    INT 21h 

    mov ax,3100h       ; to make my program resident 
    mov dx,1           ; in the memory
    int 21h


ISR proc  
    push ax
    nop      ; do nothing
    pop  ax
    iret
ISR endp
```

In ISR I do nothing because the main goal I aim to is to make the original int9 don't point to interrupt vector table that contain int9 but point to my ISR then the scancode will missed and that's what I want.... unfortunately for me that code does not work well at all and I don't know why!
thanks for advise.

**************** Some modification ********************

```
.model tiny    
.stack 100h
.data
    old_ISR dd ?
.code
main proc far
    mov ax;@data  ;new modification
    mov ds,ax     ;new modification

    mov ah,35h                ; get interrupt vector
    mov al,09                 ; for int 9  
    INT 21h  
    mov word ptr old_ISR,BX   ; address of original int9 saved  
    mov word ptr old_ISR,ES   ; in ES:BX
    mov ah,25h                ; set interrupt vector
    mov al,09h                ; for int 9
    mov DX,offset ISR         ;is pointing to my ISR
    INT 21h 

    mov ax,3100h       ; to make my program resident 
    mov dx,1           ; in the memory
    int 21h
main endp  ; new modification

ISR proc  
    push ax
    nop      ; do nothing
    pop  ax
    iret
ISR endp
end          ; new modification
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? I mean what result do you get that is unexpected when running this?

Comment: You really should put `endp main` above `ISR proc` to end the _main_ procedure. Good idea to put `end` at the very bottom of the file.

Comment: One concern I have is whether you are trying to make an EXE or COM program. You use model TINY suggesting you might be generating a COM program (but you don't set an ORG like ORG 100h which is needd for a COM program), but you set a stack that only applies to an EXE. You don't setup the _DS_ register which also indicates a COM program. Can you show us the commands you use to assemble and link this code? And are you intending to make an EXE or COM program?

Comment: 1- I expected after running that program , the keyboard must not responding for my hits on it but that do not work.
2- Okay I will edit the code and add that you refer to .
3- I want to generate executable file >>> you refer to a critical point now , I use emu8086 and use TASM to run my code but when I double clicked on the .exe file it is said to me " This app can't run on your PC " . So, may be that is I critical problem and now I searched to solve it >>> you have any idea for that ?

Comment: So you are saying after your program terminates - the keyboard still works? Can you answer my other question, as they are important and are relevant to figuring out what is going on.

Comment: I like to disable IRQ 1:  `mov al,2` `out 21h,al`

Comment: Dirks method would work, if you don't care about processing the interrupts yourself.

Comment: This with INT 21 ??   Dirk Wolfgang Glomp

Comment: Seems this might be an XY problem. You say `This app can't run on your PC` Are you running under 64-bit Windows? I ask because you can't run 16-bit Apps under a 64-bit windows environment. You'll need to run it in an emulator or a virtual machine.

Comment: yes ! windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: See the edit to my last comment then, will explain why you are getting that error.

Comment: But I also use TASM for 64-bit windows 8 , and the same message appear !!

Comment: Yes, you are likely running a 16-bit version of TASM. Can't run 16-bit version of any program. You would need to run TASM from within something like DOSBox. If you were running a 32-bit version of Windows you'd be able to run it. But even if you did get it working that won't disable the keyboard for ALL of Winodws if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes within a DOSBox >>> mmmmmm then there is no way to run my program ?!
yes . . I want to hang the keyboard for all windows , not only for the program.

Comment: DOSBox is a piece of software (not a dos window). Where did you install TASM from?

Comment: You can't write a DOS program (even if it would run) to disable the keyboard for all of Windows. If that is what you are trying to do, then your solution won't work at all.

Comment: So , it will disable the keyboard for the program only ???!!

Comment: You would have to run your program inside of an emulator (or Virtual machine), but the keyboard would only be disabled inside the emulated environment, not the whole system.

Comment: hmmmm . So , I should search for other ways to disable the keyboard and mouse without using assembly codes

Comment: Assembly isn't the problem. If you want to Disable the mouse or keyboard for All of Windows 8 you can't use DOS programs to do it (Whether they are written in assembly or some other language). I think you need to start looking at writing Windows software, not DOS. DOS programs can't take over all of Windows 8 (even if you were using the 32-bit version). A DOS program (on 320bit Windows) can only take over the mouse and keyboard inside a DOS session, that's it. On 64-bit windows DOS programs won't even run

Comment: windows software via C language you mean ?

Comment: You can create Windows software using C or assembler. But TASM will not create Windows programs. You need a proper C or Assembler that creates Windows programs. Products like Microsoft Visual Studio, and MASM32 can generate Windows executables. But Windows programs can't call DOS routines. Software is completely different under Windows than it is for DOS.

Comment: yes . I understand that >>very thank you for that information ... Now you have any way references or tutorials like art of assembly in assembly language but for windows interruption ??

Comment: You can find a lot - use Google.

Comment: Okay , I will do my best effort in that .Thx

Answer (score 0):

For MSDOS/DOSBOX:

```
cli
mov al,2     ; disable IRQ 1
out 21h,al
sti

;------------- Main loop
P1:

in   al, 64h  ; get status
test al, 1
jz short NOKEY
test al, 20h  ; byte from PS2 mouse?
jnz short NOKEY
in   al, 60h
dec  al       ; exit if escape key pressed
jz HOME
; placeholder for checking more keys using a table of keys
NOKEY:

jmp P1
;------------------------
HOME:
cli
xor al, al    ; enable IRQ 1
out 21h, al
sti
mov ah, 1     ; clear keyboard buffer
int 16h
; placeholder for terminate program
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it for DOSBOX only but I want it for all windows.

Comment: @mostafayasin: you know that Windows versions derived from NT are proper protected-mode operating systems that don't just let user programs hook interrupt vectors, right?  You'd need to write a kernel-mode device driver or something.  This might work for DOS programs running under windows, though, in their emulated DOS environment.

Comment: @PeterCordes you may be have some right words about make a device driver , but for that I can get device driver to control a specific device that connected through a specific ports and if I programmed a kernel device driver will don't meet my needs because I want to disable and enable a specific device during the system is running without restart the OS .. Is that can achieved via  KMDF ? I don't think so.